# OpenGL framebuffer android without GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil (on Nexus 7 2012)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

How do I init the framebuffer with depth and stencil on a device which does not support `GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil` (In my case a Nexus 7 2012)?

This does not work:

```
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthStencil);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    //...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create separate renderbuffers for depth and stencil:

```
GLuint depthStencil[2];
glGenRenderbuffers(2, depthStencil);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil[0]);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil[1]);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, width, height);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil[0]);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencil[1]);
```

Comment: This does not work. I'm getting `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` ( with `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` )

Comment: Ok it turned out that I had another error in my code. The answer is correct. Thanks